# Make a Directory and Uploading files in it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this code to upload a file .I am trying to make a directory by using `rand()+time()` and upload files in it.
what is wrong with the code ?

```
if(!empty($_POST['title']) ) {
    if(isset( $_FILES['img']['name']) 
        && (  
        $_FILES['img']['type'] == "image/jpeg" 
        || $_FILES['img']['type'] == "image/jpg"
        )){   

            $temp = explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']);
            $newfilename = ($new_name = ( rand(1,99999) + time() ) ). '.' .end($temp);
            mkdir($adr = '../news_img/'.$new_name);
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] , $adr.'/'.$newfilename );
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' , 'project' );
            $sql = "
            insert into `news` values(
            NULL,
             '$_POST[title]' ,
             '$_POST[text]'  ,
             '$_POST[date]'  ,
             '$_POST[cat]'   ,
             '$_POST[sub]'   ,
             '".$adr.'/'.$newfilename."',
             '$_POST[pub]'   ,
             '$_POST[top_or_main]',
            '$_POST[src]'  )";
            mysqli_query($connect , $sql );
        }   
    }   
?>
```

if you think the code is ok , what would be the probable mistakes in other parts(like html or phpmyadmin)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You need to show us what error message you receive, and any indications to the part of the code that causes it. The "fix it for me" attitude on a copy-pasted code is [not welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here. However, this is a common misconception of most new users. So, you should edit your post a little, include any relevant information for the error you receive and formulate your other questions in a way that is more [acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

The most worrying would be SQL injection:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You are adding two integers together, you could end up with duplicate directories doing this. You want to concatenate the two integers into one string. I created a function for you.

```
/**
 * Creates a new directory with a random name based on the time and a randomly
 * generated number.
 * 
 * @param string $baseDirectoryPath The base directory where the new directory will be created
 * @return string The path to the new directory
 */
function createRandomDirctory($baseDirectoryPath) {
    $randomDirectoryName = time() . '-' . rand(1, 99999);
    $directoryPath = $baseDirectoryPath . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $randomDirectoryName;
    if (mkdir($directoryPath)) {
        return $directoryPath;
    }
    throw new Exception('Directory was not created: ' . $directoryPath);
}

$baseDirectoryPath = '../news_img';

if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {

    if (isset($_FILES['img']['name']) &&
            $_FILES['img']['type'] == "image/jpeg" ||
            $_FILES['img']['type'] == "image/jpg") {

        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['img']['name']);
        $newFileName = end($temp);
        $randomDirectory = createRandomDirctory($baseDirectoryPath);
        $imageDestination = $randomDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newFileName;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $imageDestination);

        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project');

        // always escape user input that goes into an SQL statement.
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_POSY[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }

        $sql = " insert into 
                          `news`
                        values(  NULL            ,
                                 '$_POST[title]' ,
                                 '$_POST[text]'  ,
                                 '$_POST[date]'  ,
                                 '$_POST[cat]'   ,
                                 '$_POST[sub]'   ,
                                 '$imageDestination',
                                 '$_POST[pub]'   ,
                                 '$_POST[top_or_main]',
                                '$_POST[src]'  )";

        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    }
}
```